# $\tbinom{2p}{p}-2$ is divisible by $p^3$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The problem is as follows:
Let $p>3$ be a prime. Show that $\tbinom{2p}{p}-2$ is divisible by $p^3$. The only thing I can think of is that $(2p)!-2(p!)^2$ is divisible by $p^2$ which doesn't help me much. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a combinatorial approach to this problem?
Thanks

Comment: There's a straightforward combinatorial proof that it's divisible by $p$: $\Bbb{Z}/2p$ acts on the $p$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,2p\}$ by addition mod $2p$, and this action has no fixed points and only one order-2 orbit (consisting of $\{1,3,5,\dots,2p-1\}$ and $\{2,4,6,\dots,2p\}$). Maybe you can extend this somehow?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26137/binomial-supercongruences-is-there-any-reason-for-them discusses a combinatorial proof of divisibility by $p^2$ but the accepted answer suggests that there is no combinatorial proof for divisibility by $p^3$.

Comment: Problem 14 in Chapter 1 of Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics", second edition, has several parts.  One is to give a combinatorial proof that $\binom{pa}{pb} \equiv \binom{a}{b} \mod p^2$.  The next part is to prove the same equivalence mod $p^3$, and that includes the question, "Is there a combinatorial proof?"

Comment: Note that the problem is marked [3-]: "A few students may be capable of solving a [3–] problem, while almost none could solve a [3] in a reasonable period of time."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${2p\choose p}=\frac{(2p)(2p-1)\ldots (2p-(p-1))}{p!}=\frac{2(2p-1)\ldots (2p-(p-1))}{(p-1)!}=2{2p-1\choose p-1}$$
Now by [Wolstenholme's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem)
$${2p\choose p}\equiv 2\cdot1\equiv 2\mod p^3$$
${} {} {}$

Answer (score 2):

[Wolstenholme's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem) tells us that

$$\binom {2p-1}{p-1}=1\pmod{p^3}$$
and from here...

Comment: Thats not correct, it is $1$ not $0$

Comment: Yup. Edited the typo alread. t

Answer (score 2):

$\tbinom{2p}{p} = \frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)(p+p)}{1.2...(p-1)p} = \frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2}{1.2...(p-1)}$

$\tbinom{2p}{p} -2 $ will be divisible by $p^3$

iff $ \frac{(p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)2}{1.2...(p-1)} -2 $ is divisible by $p^3$

iff $ ((p+1)(p+2)...(p+p-1)) -(p-1)! $ is divisible by $p^3$  as (2,p)=1 and (p,(p-1)!)=1

Let f(x)= $\prod_{1≤r≤p-1}(x+r) = \sum _{0≤r≤p-1}a_rx^r$ .
Then (x+1)f(x+1)=(x+p)f(x).
Putting the values  of f(x) and  f(x+1) and comparing the coefficients of the different powers of x,

for $x^p$, 1=1

for $x^{p-1}, p+a_{p-1}=pC_1+a_{p-1}$

and so on.

Clearly,p |$a_r$  and by Wolstenholme's Theorem  $p^2|a_1$

So in $\prod_{1≤r≤p-1}(p+r)$,
$a_0$ is (p-1)!,
the co-efficient of p($a_1$) is the sum of product of r taken 2 at a time,
the co-efficient of $p^2$($a_2$) is the sum of product of r taken 3 at a time and the rest terms are divisible by $p^3$.

As $p|a_2$ and $p^2|a_1$, the result follows.